# Is a multi-column index generally worth it if the second column will always only have a few entries long for each entry in the first column?

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms

If I have two columns in a table, and I plan to do lots of queries on those two columns (which would normally suggest creating a multi-column index), but I also know that each unique value in the first column will only have around 3 to 5 values in the second column, is the multi-column index still worth it vs. just having an index on the first column?  Assume I don't care about the cost of creating the index, I'm strictly interested in the extent to which the multi-column index will increase the query speed over an index for just the first column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is whether the multi-column index can cover the query or at least the `where` clause (assuming your queries are referring to filtering in the `where` clause).

In general, the answer is yes.  Consider data that looks like this:

```
x     y       datapage
a     1       datapage_1
a     2       datapage_2
a     3       datapage_3
b     1       datapage_4
. . .
```

If your query is:

```
select x, y
from t
where x = 'a' and y = 2;
```

Then, with no index, the database has to scan all data pages to find matching rows.

With an index only on `x`, the database can find all the "a" values, but it still has to load three data pages to get the `y` values.

With an index on both `x` and `y`, the database can directly go to "datapage_2".

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I should have been clearer in the question: I'm assuming the alternative to a multi-column index is just having an index on the first column.  I understand that having the multi-column index means the database can go directly to the correct row, but I'm interested in knowing the extent to which it will benefit.  In other words, is the marginal benefit any different from having an index for a table that only has 5 rows?  And if it isn't, to what extent is having an index for a table with only 5 rows faster than not having an index?

Comment: "to what extent is having an index for a table with only 5 rows faster than not having an index? " MySQL probably won't even use a index on a table which has only 5 rows. @NathanWailes.. Besides it is to hard to explain how the MySQL optimizer works.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thanks for the response.  That's exactly my point: how is the marginal benefit of a multi-column index over a single-column index in the situation I described any different from the marginal benefit of an index for a table that only has five rows?

Comment: @NathanWailes . . . This presents the three scenarios.  If you only have an index on the first column, you need to fetch the data pages to get the values.  As for the relationship between values for a specific column and the number of rows in a table, there is no relationship.  In a small table, all rows are on the same data page (under most reasonable circumstances).

Comment: @GordonLinoff I see, so the two scenarios are not analogous because in my multi-column situation the different rows are likely going to be on different data pages, and the pulling of those data pages will result in additional slow-down.  I wasn't familiar with the concept of a data page but I just looked it up.  Thank you for the clarification.